# Is data transfer through a WPA2 protected ad-hoc network slower as compared to a unsecure one?

Tags: latency, ad-hoc-network, wpa2-psk

We play multiplayer LAN games on our laptops by creating wifi ad-hoc connection (sometimes protected to ensure no one other than whom we want to, joins in). Now my question is how much using a secure connection affects latency?

Why I'm asking is that since data needs to be encrypted and decrypted on the end-points so it must be taking some time and must be adding up to latency. Moreover encryption and decryption consume extra processor usage which should also affect other processes running on the system especially heavy processor using stuff like games.

So, does anyone know how much secure connection affects all this and whether it actually affects experience noticeably, may be based on some benchmark tests?

Comment: my hunch would be it wont affect it to any noticable degree, as the encryption is of a low stregth (relitively, cryptographically speaking). At least nothing noticable above the latency introduced by using wifi for gaming in the first case.